# "Make me not sleep" or "Make me not to sleep"?

Tags: word-usage

In [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/make_1?q=make),

> make somebody/something do something: to cause somebody/something to
>   do something

Ex: make me sleep

But how to negative "**sleep**"?

"**Make me not sleep**" or "**Make me not to sleep**"?

"**Make me not sleep**" sounds strange

"**Make me not to sleep**" sounds good but seem grammar is not ok

Comment: @user3169 - "Don't make me sleep" means something different from "make me not sleep".

Comment: @stangdon I understand your point, but wouldn't it be better if the OP clearly stated what he'd like to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your first guess is correct: if you want to negate the action that someone is trying to make you do, to mean "cause me to (do the opposite of something) then use "not".**

"Make me not sleep" = "Force me to *not* sleep", or "Force me to stay awake".

Note that this is different from "Don't make me sleep", which means "Do not force me to sleep".

If "make me not _____" sounds unusual, it may be because we don't usually phrase the imperative "make me ____" in the negative; we would be more likely to say something like "make me *stay awake*" or "*keep me from sleeping*."